# Upslope and downslope distance or area using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, network-analyst, road

Is there a possibility to determine the surface area above the road and the surface of the terrain below the road or between two or more roads? I want to pull the trees down the hill and up the hill to the roads. The price of skidding trees is different so I would like to know what the surface (ha) is above and below the road?

[image]

Here is an example, orange is uphill and red is downhill.
I think this is solved with a raster calculator

[image]

Here is the method, but I do not know how to solve it in ArcGIS Desktop

[image]

Comment: I think you need to be a bit clearer about the 'rules' you'll use to define above and below the road. If the road slopes, a tree can be both above and below the road at different points.

Comment: It just needs to paint the surface automatically above and below the road. Slope is only rule

Comment: But if your road starts at 10m AOD and ends at 50m AOD, a tree at 25m AOD is both above and below the road

Comment: I mean perpendicular from road. See arrows

Comment: OK but perpendicular is a line so can't have an area

Comment: Forget trees, only terrain is important.(above, below)

Comment: Here's a picture to clarify what I mean. Is the central piece of land above or below the road https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/hairpin-bend-9627092.jpg

Comment: Serpentines appear less, they catch a small surface. I have DEM 20X20 m per pixel. I dont know, maybe it couldn't be solved

Answer (score 2):

In ArcGIS, convert the road to a raster using Polyline to Raster.  Using your surface model create a flow direction raster using the Spatial Analyst Hydrology tools.  Use the flow direction raster and the rasterized road to generate a watershed using the Watershed tool.  The resulting watershed will be all the areas that are uphill of the road.

Comment: I have got some unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

One way I can think of is to convert your DEM raster to points. Then use v.to.points to get points at equal spacing along the roads layer.

Use v.sample on the road points layer to get the height value from original DEM.

Next, use the NNJoin plugin to join each DEM point to the nearest road point. You should now have a points layer that covers your study area, gives the height of the point and the height of the nearest road point.

Use field calculator to subtract the height of the nearest road point from the point height.

Interpolate a surface from these points.

reclassify the interpolated raster to positive numbers = 1 (above), negative numbers = 0 (below)

Comment: See an example, I think this is solved with a raster calculator

Comment: Please could you post your solution as an answer? I'd be interested to know how you did it

Comment: This is not my solution, I find research work with that analysis. I add another picture to my question

Comment: QGIS does not have an equivalent to ArcGIS' Path distance allocation tool (as far as I know). I have amended my answer to replicate the methodology you've outlined.

Comment: SAGA plugin have Proximity raster and can make allocation distance

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment directly on an answer yet, but to add more details about input parameters for the Path Allocation Distance gp tool in ArcMap (IMO a bit more detail in nagib's answer would be helpful).

The "in_surface_raster" parameter equals your DEM (I hydrologically conditioned my DEM first).  The "in_source_data" parameter is the road raster created in step 1 of nagib's answer.

The "in_cost_raster" parameter in path distance allocation tool for this type of analysis considers at least slope and land cover.  Here's a helpful link for creating a cost surface raster combining those two variables: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/creating-a-cost-surface-raster.htm

Also, in the path distance allocation tool help it suggests using the 
 output of Aspect gp tool (in other words, an aspect raster) in the "in_horizontal_raster" parameter of the path allocation distance gp tool.