# Delineating adverse/favourable areas adjacent to roads using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, dem, lidar, slope

I have a client in the forestry sector that would like me to run some maps with criteria that I’ve never managed for.
These maps will delineate (using polygons) areas of slope (0-20%,20-40%,>40%), distance from road centreline (0-125m, 125-250m, 250-350m, >350m) and “adverse” and “favourable” skids for a given “block area”.

The slope polys and distance buffers are easy enough to produce; I do this all the time.

The challenge for me will be figuring out how to identify the skid conditions. To give more insight on that, a “favourable” skid is defined as an area where harvested wood will be moved “downhill” to a road for decking. An “adverse” skid would be an area where the machine has to skid wood uphill. So this ultimately comes down to the location of the road, the +/- condition of the slope, and the aspect of the slope relative to the road. 
It’s a fairly complex condition to analyze, but I’m sure it can be done. My client is asking me to replicate another GIS contractor’s version of this product… which I am fairly certain is generated with some sort of model or script.

Has anyone done anything similar, or have any insight on how I could achieve these results?

I am running ArcGIS 10.3 and use anything from 1m-20m DEM and LiDAR datasets, but each block has its own constraints.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Slope](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/slope.htm) tool? Or are you needing a more specific approach?

Comment: Hi. Yes the slope tool is what I use to generate a slope raster which I convert in to classified polygons to highlight areas. The question is, from these areas, I need to identify which ones will be positive or negative in relation to their closest road (lets say in a 300m buffer). Obviously all slopes are either positive or negative, but this analysis needs to take lines of force (for lack of a better term) in to consideration.

Comment: Delineate road catchment, or perhaps try road segments subcatchments using hydrology tools. Anything within catchment is good for skid

Comment: Can you elaborate. I am not too familiar with hydrology tools... I`m not trying to identify areas that are good for skid. Instead, I need to identify areas that are either adverse or favourable.

Comment: You need to ping user name if you'd like to be heard. If water doesn't reach road from certain cell it means that cell sits below. I'll post solution later, read help on tools in a meantime.

Comment: This has been answered here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250259/upslope-and-downslope-distance-or-area-qgis-2-18-11-maybe-arcmap/250341#250341

Comment: Be carefull with accepted solution (by author himself) in hyperlink, because it is wrong. If you look at pink islands inside green, you'll see that solution suggests drag trees to the ridge before moving them to the road, instead of moving them downhill to the road that is slightly far away as crow fly. Last solution is correct one.